# Exponential Function Equation and inverse Pre-Cal

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, inverse

I am not completely sure if I wrote the equation correctly.
[image]

For A I wrote: $m(t)=100(b^x)$
Not sure it is correct...but how do I find the inverse? That doesn't make sense to me. Do I use log?

Comment: Please align your image properly or type it out.

Comment: I rotated the picture because I couldn't avoid tilting my head - still it would be better if you could type it out.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

$t = 0$:  $M(0) = 100 = 100(0.84^0)$

$t = 1$:  $M(1) = 84 = 100(0.84^1)$

$t = 2$:  $M(2) = 70.56 = 100(0.84^2)$

So that an equation modeling this relationship is $M(t) = 100(0.84^t)$
(similar to what you have written).

To find the inverse function, we can

1) replace $M(t)$ with $y$

2) solve for $t$

3) replace $y$ with $t$ and replace $t$ with $(M^{-1})(t)$:

\begin{align*}
M(t) & = 100(0.84^t)\\
y & = 100(0.84^t)\\
\frac{y}{100} & = 0.84^t\\
\ln\left(\frac{y}{100}\right) & = \ln(0.84^t)\\
\ln\left(\frac{y}{100}\right) & = t \cdot \ln(0.84)\\
\frac{\ln\left(\frac{y}{100}\right)}{\ln(0.84)} & = t
\end{align*}

So, 
\begin{align*}
(M^{-1})(t) & = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{100}\right)}{\ln(0.84)}\\ 
            & = \frac{\ln y - \ln 0.84}{\ln 0.84}\\
            & = \frac{\ln y}{\ln 0.84} - 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You can right click on a mathematical equation to see how it is formatted with LaTeX.

Comment: You made errors in the last two steps.  If $b, x, y > 0$ with $b \neq 1$, then $\log_b \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = \log_b x - \log_b y$.